# Escritura binaria en archivo falla, salta IOException

Tags: java, stream

Tengo estos dos métodos. Me salta la excepción capturada en `guardarBin()` (la primera, no la de cerrar fichero) al llamarlo despues de `escribirCodigos()` y no sé por qué es. Una ayuda por favor.

```
private static File archivoBin = new File("cuentas.dat");
private static ArrayList<Sucursal> datosSucursal = new ArrayList<Sucursal>();

public static void guardarBin() {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archivoBin));
        oos.writeObject(datosSucursal);


    } catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println("Ha habido algún problema en la escritura del archivo.");
    } finally {
        try {
            oos.close();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("No se ha podido cerrar el archivo");
        }
    }
}

public void escribirCodigos() {
        Scanner entradaCodigos=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca el número de la entidad: ");
        String entidad = entradaCodigos.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el número de la oficina: ");
        String oficina = entradaCodigos.nextLine();
        String regex = "^\\d{4}+";
            while(!entidad.matches(regex)) {
                System.out.println("La entidad deben ser 4 dígitos. Vuelva a introducirlos: ");
                entidad = entradaCodigos.nextLine();
            }
            while(!oficina.matches(regex)) {
                System.out.println("La oficina deben ser 4 dígitos. Vuelva a introducirlos: ");
                oficina = entradaCodigos.nextLine();
            }
        Sucursal inicio = new Sucursal(Integer.parseInt(entidad), Integer.parseInt(oficina));
        datosSucursal.add(inicio);      
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? Cuando ocurre una excepción, la máquina de Virtual de Java muestra información detallada sobre dicha excepción.

Comment: Para la deteccion de errores viene muy bien el método printStackTrace() del objeto Excepcion. Te dice la ruta que sigue el error a lo largo de las clases y además te dice qué error es exactamente. Ejemplo catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}

Comment: Salta el bloque `catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println("Ha habido algún problema en la escritura del archivo.");
    }` . La salida solo imprime el mensaje y el programa sigue ejecutandose. Voy a intentarlo con el método que me comentas @Jesús y comento si no consigo solucionarlo. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Solucionado. La clase `Sucursal` no tenía implementada la interfaz `Serializable`.

Comment: No olvides de agregarle un campo estático llamado [serialVersionUID](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/serialization/serialversionuid/) en la clase `Sucursal`. De lo contrario, tendrás problemas.